# VBA fill cells randomly by 0 and 1

Tags: excel, vba

So i have to make a VBA, where i have to randomize 0s and 1s.
I've made a really basic version which fills the cells with only 1s

```
Sub numberchangenormal()

Dim targetrange As Range
    Dim Cell As Range

Set targetrange = Range("A1:D1")

For Each Cell In targetrange
 Cell.Value = Int(1)
Next Cell


Set targetrange = Range("F1:I1")

For Each Cell In targetrange
 Cell.Value = Int(1)
Next Cell

End Sub
```

In the first four rows (A1:D1) I need only one 1 (the rest is 0) Example:

|   0   |   0   |   1   |   0   |

In the second four rows (F1:I1) I need atleast one 1 (the rest is 0 or 1) Example:

|   1   |   0   |   1   |   1   |

Comment: Your first part is "pick a random number between 1 and 4".  Second part is also very close to that.  Please update your question to show what you already tried, and what problems you ran into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only one *1* in A:D then find a random number and fill it in.

```
redim arr(1 to 4) as long

arr(application.randbetween(1, 4)) = 1

range("A1:D1") = arr
```

If there has to be at least one *1* but could be more then randomize and check to see if at least one array element is a *1*. If not, use the method above to ensure at least one *1*.

```
redim arr(1 to 4) as long

arr(1) = application.randbetween(0, 1)
arr(2) = application.randbetween(0, 1)
arr(3) = application.randbetween(0, 1)
arr(4) = application.randbetween(0, 1)

if (arr(1) + arr(2) + arr(3) + arr(4)) = 0 then
    arr(application.randbetween(1, 4)) = 1
end if

range("F1:I1") = arr
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the cells can be assigned at once :

```
Sub numberchangenormal()
    [a1:d1,f1:i1] = "=RANDBETWEEN(0,1)"     ' set Excel formula to all of the cells
    [a1:d1] = [a1:d1].Value                 ' optional to convert the formulas to values
    [f1:i1] = [f1:i1].Value
End Sub
```